# TNS Port not available in Oracle 11g Express Edition Installation Issue

Tags: windows, oracle11g, installation, port

Windows 7 64 bit Machine.

I'm trying to Install Oracle Database 11g express edition. I've used it many times in the past with no problem. Recently my work machine was rebuilt, and while trying to install oracle, on the step that shows TNS port, MTS Port, and HTTP Port, it will not accept the default 1521 port, or any other port I try (I've tried quite a few). Message box says "Port 1521 is in use. Specify a different port number. This port is not in use that I can tell.

I don't see a log for the install either, I looked on line to see where it should be, but I don't have a log file for the installation (That I've been able to find)

netstat -na does not show any of port's i've tried to be in use. I also tried grepping for them.

netstat -na | grep 1521 (This did not return anything)

Wondering if anyone else has seen this, or has any ideas how to get around this or trouble shoot it? I've never had this issue before.

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Could be some sort of firewall-type software preventing the app from creating sockets.

Answer (score 13):

Had this same problem. Regardless of what port i put, it would say "port already in use'. Solution was to change to a port known to be open, then click the back button on the installer until you get back to the first installer screen, then continue clicking next. This will install on your specified http port.

Answer (score 9):

I think it's a **bug from the install wizard** too. I've Windows 8 64 bits. "Back and Next" is the solution.

Comment: It's better to post you opinion in comment section, not as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same. I think it's a bug from the install wizard.

In fact, like you i specified an available port (after a check with an netstat command on line), then i had this warn screen wwith the message "Port 8081 is in use. Specify a different port number".

The thing is, when you have this screen, try to go back to the beginning of the install wizard,
then go next from the beginning to the part "Specify Database Port" and by magical when you insert the same port : you manage to access at the next step.

Bye!

Comment: Yes, the back and next fixed it.

Answer (score -3):

try running the setup from a local drive. i think you are running the setup from a mapped drive or usb or something like that. hopefully you managed anyway already ;)